# Get data of only nested object in response

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, api

[Response Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl9v0.png)

How can I get data of only category inside the 0th object and so on? This is my code.

```
$products = Product::where('market_id', $marketId)->with('category')->groupBy('category_id')->get();
    return $products;
```

Answer (score 0):

nevertheless, I figured out how to do it

```
$products = Product::where('market_id', $marketId)->with('category')
->groupBy('category_id')->get();
    $categories = $products->pluck('category');
    return $categories;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$users = DB::table('products')
            ->where('market_id', $marketId)
            ->join('categories', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->select('products.*', 'categories.name AS category_name', 'categories.description AS category_description')
            ->groupBy('category_id')
            ->get();
```

You can choose the properties you want but if they are repeated in both tables you must use an alias.

Comment: I needed to use models as I had appended some data in them but thanks.